# Where is Firebug's Cookies panel gone?

Tags: firefox, cookies, panel, firebug

Firebug doesn't show me the Cookies panel anymore. Somebody knows why?

[image: Missing Cookies panel]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You got automatically switched to the [Firefox DevTools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools) (with Firebug theme), because Firebug is discontinued and doesn't work anymore in [multi-process Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiprocess_Firefox). See the [related Mozilla Hacks blog post](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/12/firebug-lives-on-in-firefox-devtools/) for more info.

The equivalent to the Cookies panel in Firebug is the [Storage Inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Storage_Inspector), which not only allows you to inspect cookies but also the local and session storage, the cache and IndexedDB entries.

[image: Storage Inspector showing cookies]

This tool needs to be enabled via the settings, though.

[image: Option to enable Storage Inspector]

This and other things are mentioned in the [migration guide for Firebug users](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Migrating_from_Firebug).