# Where can I see the local storage in Firefox Developer Edition?

Tags: firefox, firefox-addon, firebug

I am using the Firefox Developer Edition. I cannot seem to find where to view a website's local storage. I also downloaded and installed Firebug.

[image: DOM panel]

In Chrome Developer Tools it's here:

[image: Chrome DevTools local storage]

Any advice appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Like mentioned in an [answer to a similar question related to cookies](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42167882/432681), you need to enable the [Storage Inspector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Storage_Inspector) first.

[image: Option to enable Storage Inspector]

Within the Storage Inspector you'll be able to see the local storage.

[image: Local Storage in Storage Inspector]

*Also note what you're seeing is a Firebug theme for the [Firefox DevTools](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools), it is **not** Firebug. Firebug is officially discontinued and doesn't work in [multi-process Firefox](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/Firefox/Multiprocess_Firefox) as explained in the [related Mozilla Hacks blog post](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2016/12/firebug-lives-on-in-firefox-devtools/).*

Comment: Happy I could help. Note that there is also a [migration guide for Firebug users](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Tools/Migrating_from_Firebug) explaining the differences between Firebug and the DevTools.